# List view item swipe left and swipe right?

Tags: android, listview

Can a List view item respond to swipe left and swipe right?

If so, how to apply android swipe left or right scrolling to open different intent? I want same like Call phone or message on contact view in android by default.

Thanks

Comment: May be this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures

Comment: Please note the contacts thing you're talking about only applies to Samsung phones.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this:

```
navigaList.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);
navigaList.setOnItemClickListener(listener);

OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                            long arg3) {
        if(swipeDetector.swipeDetected()) {
            if(swipeDetector.getAction() == Action.RL) {

            } else {

            }
        }        
    };
```

**SwipeDetector.java**

```
public class SwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public static enum Action {
        LR, // Left to Right
        RL, // Right to Left
        TB, // Top to bottom
        BT, // Bottom to Top
        None // when no action was detected
    }

    private static final String logTag = "SwipeDetector";
    private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    private Action mSwipeDetected = Action.None;

    public boolean swipeDetected() {
        return mSwipeDetected != Action.None;
    }

    public Action getAction() {
        return mSwipeDetected;
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();
            mSwipeDetected = Action.None;
            return false; // allow other events like Click to be processed
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            upX = event.getX();
            upY = event.getY();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;
            float deltaY = downY - upY;

            // horizontal swipe detection
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                // left or right
                if (deltaX < 0) {
                    Logger.show(Log.INFO,logTag, "Swipe Left to Right");
                    mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
                    return true;
                }
                if (deltaX > 0) {
                    Logger.show(Log.INFO,logTag, "Swipe Right to Left");
                    mSwipeDetected = Action.RL;
                    return true;
                }
            } else 

                // vertical swipe detection
                if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // top or down
                    if (deltaY < 0) {
                        Logger.show(Log.INFO,logTag, "Swipe Top to Bottom");
                        mSwipeDetected = Action.TB;
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (deltaY > 0) {
                        Logger.show(Log.INFO,logTag, "Swipe Bottom to Top");
                        mSwipeDetected = Action.BT;
                        return false;
                    }
                } 
            return true;
        }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: why you dont share all source code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `OnTouchListener` and catch padding,initial and current motion movement on list items by `MotionEvents` like `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`,`UP` or `CANCEL`.