# ListView with both side swipe

Tags: android

how to implements the listview in android to swipe from both side and only one row at a time can be swipe ,if another row is swipe the the previous row should get closed.
any suggestion would be appreciate ...
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List view item swipe left and swipe right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520750/list-view-item-swipe-left-and-swipe-right)

Comment: I think this library will provide help regarding https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Comment: examples on the link you provided are the same ,

Comment: because if user swipes the one row ,it should close the earlier row from listview,but examples are shown there,are opening multiple rows